# How to catch download link generated after buttonclick event

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, internet-explorer-9

So as for input:
I am using C# and Selenium Webdriver to automate some verification on a website. Browser is IE9.

The steps that I am working on:
I have a table that was generated by ajax query. When I click print button it returns me a file to download that can be printed. 
The issue that I need to catch the link to the file that is proposed for downloading and I have run out of ideas how to do that.

So I would be grateful to hear any advice of skilled users =).

***Updated 08/01/14:*** 
Ups sorry, I forgot to say that there is no link, actually button click triggers either a JS or ajax request that creates a document and then only then the link is generated and Open/Save IE dialog is displayed.

**Updated**
Link HTML

```
<a id="ucRadGrid_lnkPrintPDF" onclick="ucRadGrid.print();" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucRadGrid','PDF')">
```

Answer (score 0):

What i do, is i never allow my webdriver to manage a download.  What i'll do is use pure C# to download the file for me.

You can do this simply by finding the link's href attr, and downloading that.  Here is some pseudo-code:

```
var href = driver.FindElement(By.ID("download_link").GetAttribute("href");'
DownloadFile(href, "my file.ext");
```

From there, you can do what you need to.  Validate the text using pure C#, etc.

**EDIT** After your comment below:

What you can to do is find the URL of the resource you want to download.  That might require even playing around with the JS in the page.  Find the function that downloads the file, and either execute that code, or parse through the function for the URL, and then execute `DownloadFile`

Comment: Ups sorry, I forgot to say that there is no link, actually button click triggers either a JS or ajax request that creates a document and then only then the link is generated and Open/Save IE dialog is displayed.

Comment: Could you explain your edit with the help of an example please.

Comment: the only thing you're missing @Sohaib is `DownloadFile` you need to put that method. There are all kinds of tutorials out there on how to download a Url to a file.

Comment: I can implement that easily I only wanted to know how to get that href if say the button has html as follows `<input value="Download" class="mini clear download" id="download_626643" name="download_626643" data-type="" data-row-idx="0" type="button">`. What I mean to say is that it has no onClick() that I can identify.